# How to separate library's API and its implementation

Tags: c++, cmake, dll, c++17

I've got a library (static or shared, depending on `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`) with an API that the user will be linking against. I want to supply different implementations to that API in other libraries (static or shared, depending on `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`). If both libraries are static then I can link implementation library to main library and everything builds fine.
However, I've got a problem with unresolved external symbols when trying to build both libraries as shared.

An example:

- `CMakeLists.txt`

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.0 FATAL_ERROR)
    project(example)
    add_subdirectory(src)
```

- `src/CMakeLists.txt`

```
    add_library(example example.cpp)
    target_include_directories(
        example
        PUBLIC
        "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
        PRIVATE
        "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>"
    )
    target_compile_features(example PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
    
    include(GenerateExportHeader)
    generate_export_header(
        example
        EXPORT_MACRO_NAME EXAMPLE_EXPORT
        EXPORT_FILE_NAME "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/example/export.h"
        STATIC_DEFINE EXAMPLE_STATIC
    )
    
    add_library(example-impl example_impl.cpp example_impl.h)
    target_include_directories(
        example-impl
        PRIVATE
        "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
        "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>"
    )
    target_compile_features(example-impl PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

- `include/example/example.h`

```
    #pragma once
    
    #include <example/export.h>
    
    namespace EX {
        class EXAMPLE_EXPORT Example {
          public:
            virtual ~Example() = default;
    
            void func1();
            virtual void func2() = 0;
        };
    }
```

- `src/example.cpp`

```
    #include <example/example.h>
    
    namespace EX {
        void Example::func1() {}
    }
```

- `src/example_impl.h`

```
    #pragma once
    
    #include <example/example.h>
    
    namespace EX {
        class ExampleImpl : public Example {
        public:
            ExampleImpl();
            ~ExampleImpl() override;
    
            void func2() override;
        };
    }
```

- `src/example_impl.cpp`

```
    #include "example_impl.h"
    
    namespace EX {
        ExampleImpl::ExampleImpl() {}
        ExampleImpl::~ExampleImpl() {}
        void ExampleImpl::func2() {}
    }
```

`example` target compiles fine. However, when trying to compile `example-impl` target, I get the following errors:

```
    1>example_impl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl EX::Example::~Example(void)" (__imp_??1Example@EX@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __cdecl EX::ExampleImpl::~ExampleImpl(void)" (??1ExampleImpl@EX@@UEAA@XZ)
    1>example_impl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl EX::Example::Example(void)" (__imp_??0Example@EX@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl EX::ExampleImpl::ExampleImpl(void)" (??0ExampleImpl@EX@@QEAA@XZ)
```

It seems that the only solution would be to link `example` to `example-impl`. Is there any known pattern to achieve separation between library with an API and its implementation?

Comment: A code API and its implementation is called a library. You do not separate the API from the implementation into different libraries. You must provide both to make a single library.

Comment: Your `example-impl` is not an alternative implementation for `example`. It is an extension as seen by the inheritance. You have to provide an alternative implementation for `example` directly if you want to switch between implementations. There is no difference between your `example-impl` and any other code which consumes the `example` library, therefore you have to link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create different implementations for the same library, you have some options.

You can either create separate source files in the same library and select which one to compile depending on build options.

```
// example.h
class EXPORT Example
{
    virtual int f();
};

// example_a.cpp
int Example::f() { return 1; }

// example_b.cpp
int Example::f() { return 2; }

// CMakeLists.txt
add_library(example PUBLIC example.h)
if (USE_A)
    target_sources(example example_a.cpp)
else()
    target_sources(example example_b.cpp)
endif()
```

Or you can create an INTERFACE base target with the headers and use it in both library targets

```
// Using the same example.h, example_a.cpp, and example_b.cpp as above

// CMakeLists.txt
add_library(example_headers INTERFACE)
target_sources(example_headers INTERFACE example.hpp)

add_library(example_a example_a.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example_a example_headers)

add_library(example_b example_b.cpp)
target_link_libaries(example_b example_headers)
```

If you want to extend the `Example` class in another library, you have to link to the original library which defines the base functionality. This is not the same as replacing the implementation.

You can also provide multiple derived classes and select the one to use at runtime.

```
// create_example.h
EXPORT Example* create_example(int which);

// create_example.cpp
class ExampleA : public Example { ... };
class ExampleB : public Example { ... };

Example* create_example(int which)
{
    if (which == create_examplea_constant)
        return new ExampleA();
    else if (which == create_exampleb_constant)
        return new ExampleB();
    else
        return nullptr;
}
```

But if `create_example` is defined in another library it still has to link to the `example` library.